# Gridview app launcher inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview

As the title says, I need to create a custom app launcher inside a fragment. I've based my code in several answers I've readed around here, anyway, I don't get to show any app on it.

This is the adapter class:

```
public class ShortcutAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<ResolveInfo> appsList;
    PackageManager mPackageManager;


    public ShortcutAdapter(List<ResolveInfo> appsList, Context mContext) {
        this.appsList = appsList;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        mPackageManager = mContext.getPackageManager();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        ResolveInfo resolveInfo = appsList.get(position);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(resolveInfo.loadIcon(mPackageManager));

        return imageView;
    }
}
```

And this is the fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_layout, container, false);

    GridView mGrid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    //Load list on adapter
    mGrid.setAdapter(new ShortcutAdapter(loadApps(), getContext()));

    //Listener gridview items
    mGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ResolveInfo checkedResolveInfo = (ResolveInfo) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            ActivityInfo clickedActivityInfo = checkedResolveInfo.activityInfo;

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            intent.setClassName(
                    clickedActivityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
                    clickedActivityInfo.name);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return view;
}


/*Load apps*/
private List<ResolveInfo> loadApps() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    List<ResolveInfo> appsList = getActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
    return appsList;
}
```

The code is the same that you can find in several tutorials about this around internet, but in my case, I don't achieve to show any app in the GridView.

EDIT-  xml gridview layout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="120dp"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of below will cause no app icon to display.

1. `ShortcutAdapter#getCount()` return 0;

   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return 0;
   }
2. `(GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);` GridView have a narrow width. You can add a background and check it.
3. `Fragment` add in a `ViewGroup` which has a wrong narrow width. You can add a background and check it.

Comment: I've edited the post to add the gridview. Anyway, I see that at `getCount()` and `getItemId()` methods I have `return 0`. What should I put there then?